# Unable to create a Connection with Jira - JiraRestClient

Tags: java, maven, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api, maven-dependency

I am trying to create a JiraRestClient using Basic authentication.

```
JiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
    URI jiraServerUri = new URI("*");
    try (JiraRestClient restClient = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraServerUri, username, password)) {
        App.restClient = restClient;
        final Issue issue = getIssue("DEV-1");
        System.out.println(issue.getDescription());
```

However, I am getting the below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/atlassian/fugue/Suppliers
at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.ApacheAsyncHttpClient.<clinit>(ApacheAsyncHttpClient.java:80)
at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.DefaultHttpClientFactory.doCreate(DefaultHttpClientFactory.java:61)
at com.atlassian.httpclient.apache.httpcomponents.DefaultHttpClientFactory.create(DefaultHttpClientFactory.java:36)
at ...
     Process finished with exit code 1
```

I think something is missing or wrong. But not sure which one...

Here is the snippet from my pom:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
      <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
      <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.atlassian.fugue</groupId>
      <artifactId>fugue</artifactId>
      <version>4.7.2</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>JiraIntegratorLibrary</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

What am I missing here?